# Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I have this piece of code in Swift (4.2):

```
let totalQNbr = theArray.reduce(0) {
    (total, arg1) -> Int in
    let (CustomType, Int) = arg1
    let y = arg1.0.val_Number,
    x:Int = Int(y) // Problem line !!!
    return total + x
}
```

On the line, where I do a ususal type conversion, commented // Problem line !!!

I am getting this error message:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'
```

Can anybody see what I am supposed to do here?

I have seen a couple of related post, but no clear solution.

Comment: `let (CustomType, Int) = ...` – calling a local variable “Int” is a bad idea ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a great example what happens if you don't conform to the naming convention that variable names have to start with a lowercase letter.

You are declaring a local variable `Int` – which is not a function – in

```
let (CustomType, Int) = arg1
```

It hides the `Int` struct. **Don't do that**. Declare variables always starting with a lowercase letter.

```
let (customType, int) = arg1
```

However both variables are unused anyway.

And don't annotate types the compiler can infer

```
x = Int(y)
```

Comment: Oh yeah. I see, I had been messing with auto completion to get somehow my reduce syntax work .. and that's the result. I understand the bad practice about types. The unused variable are just there because it's temporary dev code..... Now it works.